# Ubuntu 23.10 doesnt accept pwd from external keyboard on boot up

Tags: 23.10

Ubuntu 23.10 doesn't accept pwd from external keyboard on boot up.

Comment: is this actually a hardware issue? Is the external keyboard even recognised in bios when booting? If your password contains numbers, are you using the number keypad without it being set? [edit] your question with more details in order to make the question answerable.